# Discord.js Music Bot Queue System - Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a music bot using a YouTube tutorial series and I am now trying to make a music queue system. The video I am using his here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lY8v9pzDMM&list=PL6guWYQhlpHEqYCgb21u6nVNDRawHIDsR&index=3

When I do the command _play and put a URL after it, it gives the error:

> Cannot read property 'active' of undefined
>   In my bot.js files I have defined 'active'.

See here:

```
const active = new Map();

let ops = {
    active: active
}
```

Does anyone know why I have the error?
To see my full code see here: https://hastebin.com/eluvuhocuy.js (It is three js files in one hastebin file - see comments to see where files start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `ops` variable only exists in your `bot.js` file. If you want to access it from your other files, you can either make it global using

```
// NOT recommended; global variables are generally considered bad
global.ops = { active }
```

or set it as a property of your `bot` object, which gets passed to your other commands:

```
// in bot.js
bot.ops = { active }
```

and then access it in your other files by changing `ops.active` to `bot.ops.active`.
I hope this helps!

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much! Also, great for a new user!